# EF6 Code first migration Oracle ODP.Net PLS-00103

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, odp.net

I'm using EF6 with Oracle ODP.Net and Code First migration in my app.

When i run

> Update-Database

I'm getting:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x00001996): ORA-06550: line 1, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
```

but when i run

> Update-Database -script

The generated script works fine on my database. After trying

> Update-Database -verbose

I found that the is a difference in scripts generated by 'Update-Database -verbose'

```
begin
  execute immediate
  'create index "SYS_MZK"."IX_REALIZACJE_KURSOW_R_6940446" on "SYS_MZK"."REALIZACJE_KURSOW" ("RLK_FK_KUR_ID")';
exception
  when others then
    if sqlcode <> -1408 then
      raise;
    end if;
end;
begin
  execute immediate
  'create index "SYS_MZK"."IX_REALIZACJE_KURSO_1395326627" on "SYS_MZK"."REALIZACJE_KURSOW" ("RLK_FK_PNM_ID_AKT_POL")';
exception
  when others then
    if sqlcode <> -1408 then
      raise;
    end if;
end;
```

and 'Update-Database -script":

```
begin
  execute immediate
  'create index "SYS_MZK"."IX_REALIZACJE_KURSOW_R_6940446" on "SYS_MZK"."REALIZACJE_KURSOW" ("RLK_FK_KUR_ID")';
exception
  when others then
    if sqlcode <> -1408 then
      raise;
    end if;
end;
/

begin
  execute immediate
  'create index "SYS_MZK"."IX_REALIZACJE_KURSO_1395326627" on "SYS_MZK"."REALIZACJE_KURSOW" ("RLK_FK_PNM_ID_AKT_POL")';
exception
  when others then
    if sqlcode <> -1408 then
      raise;
    end if;
end;
/
```

The dissapearing of '/' is my problem - is there a way to change the way of generating above script

Comment: When I use the migrate.exe tool from Entity Framework, the verbose command appears to be trying to run the two commands of the migration separately (separate "VERBOSE:" messages), but the error is indicating the missing forward slash. Do you see the same with migrate.exe? As a workaround I ended up just running the script output manually into the database.